# Select values in bootstrap multiselect based on data attributes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm rather new in jquery/bootstrap coding and want to achieve the following. I have a select (using bootstrap Multiselect) with several options. Within this list, I try to select all the options that match values of an array (list1 in below code). However, instead of looking at the value op the options, I need to check on a data-attribute of the option (list 2 in below code).

**My dropdown**

```
<form>
  <select class="form-control" id="list1" multiple="multiple">
    <option data-vendorid="001" value="001">some-value-1</option>
    <option data-vendorid="002" value="002">some-value-2</option>
    <option data-vendorid="003" value="003">some-value-3</option>
  </select>

  <select class="form-control" id="list2" multiple="multiple">
    <option data-vendorid="001" value="some-value-1">some-value-1</option>
    <option data-vendorid="002" value="some-value-2">some-value-2</option>
    <option data-vendorid="003" value="some-value-3">some-value-3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**My script**

```
var arr = [{
    "attr-1": "attr-value-1",
    "attr-2": "attr-value-2",
    "id": "001"
}, {
    "attr-1": "attr-value-1",
    "attr-2": "attr-value-2",
    "id": "003"
}];

//If I look for the default value, it works:
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $('#list1').multiselect('select', arr[i].id);
}

//So I tried something like this, but can't figure it out
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $('#list2').multiselect('select', $(arr[i]).data('vendorid'));
}
```

Check [my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevenschutter/gpSqc/705/)!

Help is much appreciated

Comment: What are `"attr-1": "attr-value-1"` key-value pairs?

Comment: even in list1, you are not looking at values, but at the attribute 'id'; I feel like You have answered your own question..

Comment: @dferenc: "attr-1": "attr-value-1" > indeed, key-value pairs

Comment: @RajkumarSomasundaram: doesn't it look within my array for a key called ID? I updated the example and don't use the same name now!

Comment: Sure they are. But what they are representing? There are no attributes like that in the html snippet.

Comment: @dferenc I get these variables from a cookie, parse them and line them up in the array. I use them further on to make a readable email that doesn't contain ID's but in the back-end I need the ID's to make the magic happen. I added them in the snippet because I thought it makes it more logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think you're trying to do a data mapping like this:

```
var map = {};
$('#list2').find('option').each(function(index, elem) {
    map[$(elem).data('id')] = elem.value;
});

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $('#list2').multiselect('select', map[arr[i]['id']]);
}
```

According to the [docs of the multiselect jQuery plugin](http://loudev.com/), the `.multiselect('select', String|Array)` method expects a string or an array of option values to be selected. As you are trying to do the selectoin based on other attributes you have to make a "dictionary" that maps your stored records to the option values. That's what the example above does.

Update:
I just have updated the code to reflect the exact attribute names in your Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#list2').multiselect('select', $(arr[i]).data('id'));
```

`.data()` is a function provided by jquery, so you need to select the array element using`$` first

Comment: Mmm, this doesn't solve the issue. It makes the code work (wherefore thanks), but it doesn't look for the data attribute. I updated my fiddle to make it more logic. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevenschutter/gpSqc/706/)